# A question on graph products

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a graph product $\cdot$ that is commutative and associative such that $\alpha(G\cdot G)=\alpha(G)^2$ for all  graphs $G$ where $G\cdot G$ is the product of $G$ with itsel and $\alpha(G)$ is independence number of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

Co-normal product

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2619.pdf

equation3 is above.

here independence number is multiplicative.